# Flask-Forms 404 Error How do i get around this?

Tags: python, html, sql, flask

I am building a database using python SQL and html and while using flask i am receiving a 404 not found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. However, I am unsure what I am doing wrong. I am in the process of trying to get CRUD to run and stopped with the addition as this error came up. I can get my data to display however I cannot get the buttons to appear, I want them to appear at the top of my data. My Code is below.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

import pymysql
import creds 

def get_conn():
    conn = pymysql.connect(
        host= creds.host,
        user= creds.user, 
        password = creds.password,
        db=creds.db,
        )
    return conn

def execute_query(query, args=()):
    cur = get_conn().cursor()
    cur.execute(query, args)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return rows

def display_html(rows):
    html = ""
    html += """<table><tr><th>Breed</th><th>FurColor</th><th>EyeColor</th><th>Height</th><th>Longevity</th><th>CharacterTraits</th><th>CommonHealthProblems</th></tr>"""

    for r in rows:
        html += "<tr><td>" + str(r[0]) + "</td><td>" + str(r[1]) + "</td><td>" + str(r[2]) + "</td><td>" + str(r[3]) + "</td><td>" + str(r[4]) +"</td><td>" + str(r[5]) + "</td><td>"+ str(r[6]) + "</td></tr>"
    html += "</table></body>" 
    return html
    
@app.route("/viewdog")
def viewdog():
    rows = execute_query("""SELECT Breed,FurColor,EyeColor,Dog.Height,Health.Longevity,Health.CharacterTraits,Health.CommonHealthProblems
                FROM Dog JOIN Health using (Height) 
                ORDER BY Height """)
    return display_html(rows)
    
from flask import render_template

@app.route("/adddog", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def add_stock():
    return render_template('Dogsinfo.html')


    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

I've tried like 7 different things, all resulting in the same error

Comment: What route are you trying to access? Have you checked for typos?

Answer (score 0):

**first:** When you run a flask app it provides you with link in the terminal try to click on that it will open a new tab in the chrome or edge then write ** viewdog** at the end of already provided url.

**second**: keep **import lines** at the begining of the code.